# My boss knew I had put a file onto a memory stick?

Tags: flash-memory

The office I work for sent a email to me by accident; it contained an Excel spreadsheet that showed I was being treated illegally. I put it on a memory stick for my own future in case I needed to take it further. But when they had my laptop back when I was on holidays, they knew I had transferred it onto a stick. Could you tell me how?

Comment: Did you opened the copy from the memory stick by any chance?

Comment: The question is unanswerable.

Comment: It is answerable - https://www.google.com/search?q=software+to+monitor+file+transfers+to+usb+devices

Comment: @Bryan'BJ'Hoffpauir - yet it is still a guess ...

Comment: We will have no way to determine how *your* employer did it. There are logs and programs that exist that track this kind of thing.

Answer (score 2):

This depends on the logging which was in place on your system when you were doing the copy. Logging the file copy is not enabled by default.

There are other programs you can indirectly get that information form, specifically antivirus software which may log the history of its checks. This is also possible via the program you used to open the file with (this is dependent on which copy you opened: the one from the email or the one copied to the USB stick)

Comment: The general answer is that there is software (3rd party and, depending on your Windows Environment Group Policy / Network Config, Windows features) that allow for monitoring file copy operations onto external storage devices, as well as logs generated by security products like AV / Malware scanners that also capture data about files on external devices. https://www.google.com/search?q=software+to+monitor+file+transfers+to+usb+devices

Comment: @Bryan'BJ'Hoffpauir: correct, I indeed skipped the most obvious one (which is monitoring software specifically looking for some activities, including copying)

Comment: thanks, if I opened the filed from the usb, would they be able to tell from recent docs how it was opened did try and do a test on this but could not see anything?

Comment: As mentioned, there are several possibilities, particularly if you have opened the file from the usb. It is hard to say without knowing more which element they used but it is certainly easier after such an access. This said, if they tempered with the laptop the evidence (if this is evidence) may not be receivable by a court. It is very dependent on your particular case, country and chain of events.